# Delete specific rows from a text file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to delete a specific row from a text file using NodeJs, but I am having trouble to do so. Can anyone please help me?

This is the content inside the text file and I am trying to delete example3:example3 from the text file.

```
example1:example1
example2:example2
example3:example3
example4:example4
```

This is the code that should work but doesn't

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../data/test.txt')
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8').split('\r\n')

const position = 3

fileData.splice(position - 1, 1)
```

Comment: You are deleting an item from the in-memory `fileData` array.  If you do `console.log(fileData)`, you will see that it has been removed from that array. But, you haven't changed the file on disk at all.  If you want to change that, then you have to rewrite the modified data back to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the file with `fs.writeFile` or `fs.writeFileSync`

Synchronous:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const filePath = '../data/test.txt'

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, filePath)
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8').split('\r\n')

const position = 3

fileData.splice(position - 1, 1)
const dataString = fileData.join('\r\n')
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, dataString)
```

Asynchronous:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const filePath = '../data/test.txt'

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, filePath )

fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err

  const fileData a data.split('\r\n')

  const position = 3

  fileData.splice(position - 1, 1)
  const dataString = fileData.join('\r\n')

  fs.writeFile(filePath, dataString, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    else console.log('file saved')
  })
})
```